# Install angular on mac

Tags: node.js, angular, macos, npm

I'm trying to install Angular on macOS. I have npm 5.6.0 and node 8.11.1 installed. I tried `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`, which seems to install it. However, when I type `ng --version`, I get:

> Unknown error: ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Edit: I also tried this, to no effect:

- `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`
- `npm cache clean` or `npm cache verify` (if npm > 5)
- `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: maybe `sudo ng --version`

Comment: Also you *might* have to close and re-open your console after the initial global install

Comment: sudo ng --version doesn't change anything, and it wouldn't be acceptable to run it as an admin anyway. I also tried reopening the console, to no effect

Comment: Feel free to ask me more questions rather than downvoting my question. I don't really know what else to describe, the installation should be as simple as 'npm install', which is what I did, except that it doesn't work, so I don't know where to start looking, I'm stuck.

Comment: I can't think of any other questions. Do keep in mind that someone that responds might not be the same person(s) that down/up vote. I prefer not to down vote unless there is a poorly written question with little/no effort. In this case I just did an up vote to help you out. Good luck.

Comment: I wasn't talking to you in particular Igor. As a matter of fact, thank you for trying, it didn't help me but maybe it will help someone else with a problem similar to mine who reads this one day.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the macOS package manager. In your terminal type:

```
brew install angular-cli
```

To confirm your version:

```
ng --version
```

Comment: Assuming that [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) is installed first, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to install angular on mac is using brew.

1.) Install brew, by typing the following command on your terminal :-

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

2.) After Installing brew, then run following command :-

```
brew install angular-cli
```

After Installation, you'll see angular is successfully installed.

To check, Type Command :-

```
ng version
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete npm and node, then install them via brew (works perfect on mac os).

See https://brew.sh/

Comment: I installed it through brew indeed